# Vue 3 watchEffect dependency tracking after asynchronous code

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to understand the following note from the watchEffect [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watcheffect)

> TIP
> watchEffect only tracks dependencies during its synchronous execution. When using it with an async callback, only properties accessed before the first await tick will be tracked.

To my understanding, everything after the first await should not trigger a re-evaluation which is not the case in the following example.

```
<script setup>

import { reactive, watchEffect } from "vue"

const state = reactive({
 count: 0,
 name: 'Leo'
})

const sleep = ms => new Promise(
  resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

watchEffect(async () => {
 console.log(`Count: ${state.count}`)
 await sleep(1000) 
 console.log(`Name: ${state.name}`)
})

state.count++
state.name = 'Cristiano' 
  
</script>
```

[Vue playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9ktFrgzAQxv+VIwyq1Kp9da0wyt7G2MMefWjmzjalJiGJyhD/913UdqWD+hTi/b777rv07EXruG2QZWxjSyO0A4uu0XkhCylqrYyDHgzy0okWI+i4K4+vVYWlgwEqo2ooGPEF80CppCUBxx3C9koFfSGhVI10GaQRnSWvMYPFG6pFIYfwhjwjaiJrC9scJHbwQR2ExYAo0rPq3JJy7j1+ihpV44L5NiIoDJ+91o3HgNsfWUIQemiyIakc47M6BPvd5OmpHx3Ho8VhT36Ad1zMdoJ1mqYh3LPwPg5xYf1IIzqNcyO4XEKSADGWkpo7rqMZpwh8cn8aNPxiZ4R1gku1eEBeizwPZG+TTPvLWcSmxa1qruOTVZKW62cnlemHLVg2pkHfvL2MDkfntM2SxFalfxInGytzSOgUG+pNccdo69WXUZ1FQ8IF88u8aCR02aJZGZTfaNA80rwr/afrZQfKkg2/A8XneQ==)

The effect triggers when the name changes, which, according to the note, should not.

Comment: I see the `watcheEffect` run twice as expected. The first run is triggered immediately when you define the watcher. The second run is triggered when `state.count` is changed. You can set a 2-second timeout for `state.name = 'Cristiano'` to see it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default effect of `watchEffect` is `pre` which means in sequence of changes it will call first and last

- `watchEffect` calls itself for the first time and since it is `pre` it will run immediately
- `state.count++` is called and `watchEffect` notices the change
- `state.name = '...'` is called but `watchEffect` doesn't care
- `end main task`
- `watchEffect` sees the change complete it calls the last time of the reaction cycle as `pre`

> why `console.log(`Name :...`)` runs twice in a row is due to the nature of the asynchronous function being put into a separate task you can refer to elsewhere

> to make `watchEffect` call only once in the react cycle add `{ flush: 'post' }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand this, and it's how I expected it to work but the note in the linked docs above suggests that any change after the await should not trigger the effect. I think the note is confusing or even maybe wrong. what do you think?

Comment: @FotisAdamakis the documentation correctly states that the following code `await` is all treated as `.then()` which means it belongs to another task outside of the main task that react system listens for so `state.name` instead change will not update `watchEffect`